# GCC C warning "duplicate ‘const’ declaration "

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Why am I getting

> duplicate ‘const’ declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]

for this declaration?

```
extern uint8_t CalculateChecksum(const communicationBlock_t const *messageBlock);
```

Where `communicationBlock_t` is a struct.

I don't the function to be able to change the structure pointed to by the parameter, nor do I want it to be able to point that parameter elsewhere.

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: `const` always applies to what's on its left. If there's nothing on its left, then (and only then) it applies to what's on its right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is sufficient to write

```
uint8_t CalculateChecksum(const communicationBlock_t* messageBlock);
```

This means that you can't change the pointed-at contents. If you want to block a pointer from getting assigned to a different address, you would write `* const`.

But that isn't necessary here, `messageBlock` is a local copy of the original pointer and the caller should not care about what that function does with it internally.

This is a matter of style:

Some believe that somehow this adds extra safety by keeping the internals of the function const-qualified. They also believe that it somehow makes sense to write things like `void func (const int n)`. Many preaching this style are C++ programmers used to `const` qualify member functions - which is something else entirely and can't be done in C anyway.

Others (like me) believe that const qualifying parameters with `* const` is regarded as needless clutter that confuses the reader, since the function declaration is to be regarded as documentation for the caller of the function, not for the implementer of the function definition.

Comment: That was fantastic, thanks for writing how I feel about `* const*` (and `const` scalars in general) as arguments. Are you sure about the last point, about no conversion from `const type * const` to `const void *`?

Comment: @unwind For the case of memcpy, it is a constraint violation of the rule of simple assignment (which applies during parameter passing). From 6.5.16.1: "the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right". For the pointer conversion in general, the C standard only says what is allowed, 6.3.2.3 §2 "For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type", making it implicitly UB.

Comment: Okay ... I'm still confused because the second `const` in `const type * const` is of course not related to the type being pointed to. So it shouldn't matter? I tried it and GCC sure builds just fine when passing `const char * const` as the second argument to `memcpy()` (but of course that doesn't prove much).

Comment: @unwind Actually you are correct. The standard says "the type pointed to by the left". The type pointed to by `const type* const` is `const type`. No pointer conversion that discards qualifiers takes place, it is valid for the same reason as `const int x; int y=x;` is valid. I'll remove that part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that feels better. :) Also I have a typo in my first comment, there's an asterisk at the end of the first code-formatted text that is wrong but I can't edit, and deleting it makes this entire comment chain b0rken.

Answer (score 11):

Both of the `const` keywords you wrote apply to `communicationBlock_t`. You probably wanted this:

```
extern uint8_t CalculateChecksum(const communicationBlock_t * const messageBlock);
```

The rule is: `const` applies to the left, unless it's the leftmost specifier, then it applies to the right.

Comment: D'oh! So obvious, but I just could not see it :-/